# How to save response for particle users in output folder in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I created one thread group which has 25 users and a total of 3 samplers.
Here I used ${__threadNum} function to saw which user currently running. here request was not sequentially run. and for saving response/output I used listener 'Save Responses to a file' Here I also used counter to save every user outputs separately but problem is that when we check in output folder the saved output and response showed in the Response body are different actually this output is for another user .. so how to create a setup for every user where response and saved output is same

Answer (score 0):

If you do something like:

[image]

textual version just in case:

```
outputFolder/response-for-user-${__threadNum}-iteration-${__jm__Thread Group__idx}.txt
```

and run your test with 2 users and 2 iterations you will see the following files generated under the `outputFolder` (it will be created in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
response-for-user-1-iteration-0.txt
response-for-user-1-iteration-1.txt
response-for-user-2-iteration-0.txt
response-for-user-2-iteration-1.txt
```

---

Also be aware that it's possible to amend JMeter's [Results File Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config) so all the request and response details will be written to [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles), add the next lines to *user.properties* file:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.url=true
```

or alternatively you can save the request and response data by using any [Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html), example setup:

[image]

More information: [How to Save Response Data in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-save-response-data-in-jmeter)